# Command for adding a LaTeX template to pandoc on R

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio, pandoc

I am trying to use Pandoc to convert a .md file to PDF. In doing this, I would like to add a LaTeX template into it. Is there a way to do this? If so, what is the command for doing it in RStudio?

The command I am currently using is the following

````
```{r}
pandoc("foo.md", format="latex")
```
````

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for the template, you can use the `--template` argument for pandoc, which translates to the `template: ` configuration in [knitr's spec](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/); for RStudio, I think the answer is "not yet", but the support is likely to come eventually

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the function `system` and run pandoc directly, adding a Latex header.

For example:

> system("pandoc -f markdown -t latex -o foo.pdf -H template.tex -V papersize:\"a4paper\" -V geometry:\"top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm\" foo.md ")

-f inicates the origin language, though I mix MarkDown and Latex and it works fine.

-t is the result language, though it really compiles the created latex and what you get is a .pdf document

-o the name of the file you want to create

-H a header to add. There is where you can put your template

-V many variables that you can set. Here I set the paper size and margins

at the end you write the name of your MarkDown file

template.tex is a tex file with the header I want in the Latex document. I use it to add packages, headers and some other parameters. For example:

> \usepackage{booktabs}
>
> \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
>
> \usepackage{colortbl}
>
> \usepackage{float}
>
> \usepackage{fancyhdr}
>
> \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
>
> \setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
>
> \pagestyle{fancy}
>
> \lhead{My Title}
>
> \rhead{\includegraphics[height=50pt]{MyGraph.png}}